# Как через this удалять файл в нужном input'е?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
var file = document.getElementById('file'),
            removeBtn = document.getElementById('remove');

        removeBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            file.value = '';
        }, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file"/> <br />
<input type="button" id="remove" value="remove" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="file" id="file"/> <br />
<input type="button" id="remove" value="remove" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="file" id="file"/> <br />
<input type="button" id="remove" value="remove" />
<br />
<br />
```

как правильно изменить скрипт, чтобы можно было удалять только тот  файл, под которым находиться кнопка    удалить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, нельзя на одной странице иметь двух одинаковых `id`. Во-вторых, стоит изменить вёрстку так, чтобы поле и кнопку что-то объединяло. Например, общий родительский элемент.

```js
var removeButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
for(var i = 0; i < removeButtons.length; i++)
    removeButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var parent = event.target.parentNode;
        for(var x = 0; x < parent.childNodes.length; x++) {
            if(parent.childNodes[x].nodeName == 'INPUT' && parent.childNodes[x].type == 'file')
                parent.childNodes[x].value = '';
        }
    });
```

```html
<p>
    <input type="file" /> <br />
    <input type="button" class="remove" value="remove" />
</p>
<p>
    <input type="file" /> <br />
    <input type="button" class="remove" value="remove" />
</p>
<p>
    <input type="file" /> <br />
    <input type="button" class="remove" value="remove" />
</p>
```

Если бы взаимодействующие инпуты были написаны подряд, без тегов и текста между ними, можно бы было ещё проще с помощью атрибута [previousSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling):

```
event.target.previousSibling.value = '';
```

И напоследок ещё одно важное замечание: система безопасности браузера может не позволить изменять значение в поле типа file. Так что лучше и не пытаться.